All data in a Google Sheet not being returned using the Sheets API and Node.js
All data is not being returned in an API request to spreadsheets.values in the Sheets API using Node.js.
An example Sheet - note that in the header row, columns E-I and J-N are merged:

Code:
    async function getSheet(auth) {
        const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
        const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: '<my id>',
            range: 'Sheet1!A:ZZZ',
        });
    
        json = res.data.values
        console.log(json)
    }

What is returned - note that the third array (third row in the Sheet) is missing lots of data:
[
  [
    'Board',
    'Owner',
    'Overview',
    'URL',
    'Inputs',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'Outputs'
  ],
  [
    'ABC Board',
    'Jeff',
    'About this board...',
    'link',
    'first name',
    'last name',
    'id',
    'N/A',
    'N/A',
    'license id',
    'state'.
    'qualification',
    'accreditation',
    'fee'
  ],
  [
    'DEF Board,'
    'Jane'
  ],
  [
    'GHI Board',
    'Ahmed',
    'About this board',
    'link',
    'first name',
    'last name',
    'id',
    'state',
    'N/A',
    'birthdate',
    'country'
  ]
]

My desired output is that all rows are completely returned.
Is anyone able to help me understand what is causing a row that is clearly available in the Sheet to not be fully returned? Are the merged cells to blame? The empty cells? The code? I've tried and read many things and would be grateful for any insights.
Notes:

I can't manipulate the Sheet, its format, or the way Inputs and Outputs are entered in multiple cells instead of one. I can only read the data.
I am using v4 of the Sheets API.
If it matters, the goal is to place each row into its own templated page in a CMS (Paligo).


About My desired output is that all rows are completely returned., to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By the way, what is "Notes:"? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
